# Enviar datos por metodo POST a Web Service con Swift

Tags: php, webservice, ios, swift, post

amigos.

Estoy empezando con Swift y pretendo rellenar mediante el método `POST` mi BBDD y lamentablemente no sé dónde estoy cometiendo el error, o en el php o en el swift. BBDD Mysql.

#### Codigo PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["Name"])){

    $Name=         ( empty($_POST['Name']) )             ?  NULL  : $_POST['Name'];
    $Room=         ( empty($_POST['Room']) )             ?  ""    : $_POST['Room'];
    $Teacher_Name= ( empty($_POST['Teacher_Name']) )     ?  ""    : $_POST['Teacher_Name'];


    if ($name){

        if( $conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database) ){

            $sql= "INSERT INTO classes(Name,Room,Teacher_Name) VALUES (?,?,?)";


            if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql)) {

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$Name,$Room,$Teacher_Name);

                if( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) {
                    //$msg=printf("Insert", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
                    $msg=printf("");
                }else{
                    //$msg=printf("Error: %s ejecutando la consulta", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    $msg=printf("Account already exists");
                }

                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            }else{
                $msg=printf("Error: %s preparando la consulta", mysqli_error($conexion));
            }

            mysqli_close($conexion);

        }else{
            $msg=printf("Error de conexión: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
        }

    }else{
        $msg="El nombre estaba vacío";  
    }
    //Envia un numero de error al final
    //echo $msg;

}
```

#### Codigo Swift

```
@IBAction func onPostTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let parameters = ["Name": "Orlando", "Room": "RDR", "Teacher_Name": "Tea Lopez"]

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://zrerdo.com/Arcmmetry/postClasses.php") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }

    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    //usar Data URLRequest
    session.dataTask(with: request ) { (data, response, error) in

        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                //Elegimos jsonObject InputStream
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2):

Por si te sirve de orientación, yo lo hago con PHP utilizando PDO de la siguiente manera:

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php 

//Completar con tus datos estas variables:
//DB_HOST 
//DB_NAME
//DB_USER
//DB_PASSWORD 

try{

$str_conn="mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=utf8";

$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

}catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo 'Error al conectar a la BBDD. '.$ex->getMessage();
        die();
}

$usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
$nombre = $_REQUEST['nombre'];

if (isset($usuario)){

$res=$dbh->prepare('insert into sis_registros (id_usuario, nombre) VALUES (:usuario, :nombre);');

$res->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario, ':nombre' => $nombre));

// Cerramos la conexión y limpiamos las variables implicadas
$res->closeCursor();
$res = null;
$str_conn = null; 
$dbh = null;


} //fin del IF

?>
```

Y luego, desde una función Swift, inserto así los datos:

**Código Swift3:**

```
@IBAction func btn_enviar(_ sender: Any) {


    //crea NSURL
    let requestURL = URL(string: "https://localhost/pruebas/inserta_solicitud.php")

    //crea NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

    //configura el método de envío
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    //variables obtenidas de los campos de texto

    let usuarioD = usuario.text!
    let nombreD = nombre.text!


    //parámetros a enviar
    let postParameters = "usuario="+usuarioD+"&nombre="+nombreD;

    //agrega los parámetros a la petición
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    //crea una tarea que envía la petición post
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        //si ocurre algún error sale
        if error != nil{
            print("Error")
            return;
        }            

    }
    //ejecuta la tarea
    task.resume()

}
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Mira yo ago asi las peticiones post, si te sirve de guia, y para poder ayudarte con tu php necesito puedas probarlo con postman o algo asi para ver si si hace la insercion o ver el error que genera.

func post(){

```
        let postString = "email=\(email)&&password=\(password)&&device_type=ios&&device_token=\(token!)&&login_by=manual";
        //K.LOGIN = Ruta a hacer el post
        AuthProvider.Instance.callApi(postString, Route: K.LOGIN) { res in

            print(res)
            }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me a servido muchos.